# AngularJS 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular 1.4 in order to call a REST API but i GET

> AngularJS 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting

This is my services.js

```
(function (angular) {
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.services.dashboard', [])
        .factory('DashboardService', DashboardService);

DashboardService.$inject = ['$http', '$q', 'EndpointUrl'];

function DashboardService($http, $q, EndpointUrl) {
    function getStatus() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        return $http.get(EndpointUrl + 'status')
                .then(successRequest, failRequest);

        function successRequest(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data.data);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        ;

        function failRequest() {
            deferred.reject([]);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
        ;
    };
};

})(angular);
```

And this is my app.js

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider, $compileProvider) {
                $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');
                $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);

                $stateProvider
                        .state('dashboard', {
                            controller: 'DashboardController as dashboard',
                            url: '/app/dashboard',
                            templateUrl: '/assets/js/src/dashboard/templates/dashboard.html',
                            resolve: {
                                getStatus: function (DashboardService) {
                                    return DashboardService.getStatus();
                                }
                            }
                        });

                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/dashboard');
                $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
                delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
            })
```

My controller.js doesn't perform anything:

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.controllers.dashboard', [])
            .controller('DashboardController', DashboardController);
    DashboardController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$state', '$filter', 'DashboardService', 'DashboardPeriods', 'getStatus'];
    function DashboardController($rootScope, $state, $filter, DashboardService, DashboardPeriods, getStatus) {

    }
    ;

})(angular);
```

So i didn't really understand why i'm getting a $digest() iterations reached.
REST API just return a json that is the same every time.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

Answer (score 0):

You are returning $http Promise and then deferred.promise from your callbacks which might be causing the loop. Remove $http return. Move deferred.promise return out of callback methods and return that instead from getStatus method.

```
function DashboardService($http, $q, EndpointUrl) {
    function getStatus() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get(EndpointUrl + 'status')
                .then(successRequest, failRequest);

        function successRequest(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data.data);
        };

        function failRequest() {
            deferred.reject([]);
        };

        return deferred.promise;
    };
    return {'getStatus': getStatus};
};
```

Comment: Yes but as said before, i still get the same error.

Comment: did you remove return in front of $http?

Comment: Yes, i remove return.

Comment: i noticed that you never returned an object containing your method from your factory. that's why angular is not able to resolve it. see latest edit.

Comment: i guess the problem is somewhere else. is it something like this https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1022